# Undo Redo functionality is not working.

Tags: android, android-view, undo, redo

I am working on a drawing app for android users. I want to implement undo redo functionality on my app. I am referring questions posted on stackoverflow to solve my problem but I could not be able to find the right solution for my code. Below I am posting my code, please help me to get rid of this issue.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

 private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
 private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>(); 

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    setupDrawing();
}

public void setupDrawing(){

    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;

    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);

    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    paths.add(drawPath);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
//view given size
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //draw view
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    for(Path p : paths){
        canvas.drawPath(p, drawPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    //  undonePaths.clear();
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    //  drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        drawPath = new Path();
        paths.add(drawPath);  
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;   
}


public void onClickUndo(){
    if(paths.size()>0){
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Undo is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        invalidate();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Undo is not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void onClickRedo(){
    if(undonePaths.size()>0){
        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Redo is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        invalidate();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Redo is not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What is happening when you click undo? Does it say "Undo is not working" or are you having some undesired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minor changes.

There's an extra `Path` in your lists that will cause an Undo/Redo step to essentially do nothing when the rest is corrected. So in `setupDrawing()` remove:

```
paths.add(drawPath);
```

In the `onDraw()` method, remove:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
```

This `drawBitmap()` call was redrawing the member Bitmap that is drawn to on every `ACTION_UP`, making it appear as though your `Path` lists weren't being updated.

Then, in the `onTouchEvent()` method, in `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` un-comment:

```
undonePaths.clear();
```

and change the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` case to:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    paths.add(drawPath);  
    drawPath = new Path();
    break;
```

The `reset()` call was clearing the `Path`, which you don't want. Instead, here we add the recently completed `Path` to the list, and then create a new one to continue.

NB: The way this is currently working, the Undo/Redo functionality will not affect the `canvasBitmap`. As it is unclear what this Bitmap is for, I left it as is. If you want this Bitmap to mirror the View's, you can simply move the  `drawCanvas.drawPath()` calls to `onDraw()`, in parallel to the `canvas.drawPath()` calls there.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly without canvasBitmap. But I need to make it work with canvasBitmap. I am referring this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-drawing-app-touch-interaction--mobile-19202. Please suggest me to make it work with canvasBitmap too.

Comment: What is `canvasBitmap` for? I.e., what's its functionality?

Comment: its a pattern fill bitmap, which i can choose and draw through finger touch.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-drawing-with-pattern-fills--mobile-19527 see this link. some patterns are there like grass and sky bitmap.

Comment: "its a pattern fill bitmap" - No, it's not. It's a "buffer" that's saving the View's image between `onDraw()` calls.

Comment: can you suggest me anything to implement undo,redo functionality on it?

Comment: The way you're implementing your Undo/Redo, i.e. redrawing every Path in `onDraw()`, you don't need `canvasBitmap`. You will, however, need to keep a list of the Paint objects, too.

Answer (score -1):

```
var undoRedo = new Array();
var unStep = -1;

function historySave() {
    unStep++;
    while (undoRedo.length > 20) {
        undoRedo.shift();
        unStep--;
    }
    if (unStep !== 0 && unStep < undoRedo.length) {
        undoRedo.length = unStep;
        unStep++;
    } else {
        undoRedo.length = unStep;
    }
    undoRedo.push(document.getElementById('drawingCanvas').toDataURL());    
}

function Undo() {
    if (unStep > -1) {
        unStep--;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.src = undoRedo[unStep];
        drawingContext.clearRect(0,0,drawingCanvas.width,drawingCanvas.height);
        canvasPic.onload = function () {
        drawingContext.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0);
            }
    }
}

function Redo() {
    if (unStep < undoRedo.length - 1) {
        unStep++;
        var canvasPic = new Image();
        canvasPic.src = undoRedo[unStep];
        canvasPic.onload = function ()  { 
        drawingContext.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for Android, which is what the question is asking for?